# How to return associative arrays from function in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

```
process_ls_entry() {
    IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$1"
    declare -A LS_MAP
    LS_MAP[entry]="${array[@]::1}"
    LS_MAP[mode]="${array[@]:1:1}"
    LS_MAP[size]="${array[@]:2:1}"
    LS_MAP[num_blocks]="${array[@]:3:1}"
    timestamp="${array[@]:4}"
    timestamp=${timestamp// /_}
    LS_MAP[timestamp]="${timestamp}"
    # how to return?
}

a="temp_dir drwxr-xr-x 0 0 Fri Jul 13 07:08:00 2012"
output=( $(process_ls_entry "$a") )

# entry -> temp_dir
# mode -> drwxr-xr-x
# size -> 0
# size -> 0
# timestamp -> Fri_Jul_13_07:08:00_2012

echo ${output[timestamp]}
```

I have created a function

How to correctly return an associative array from a function in shell script?

Comment: Make them global?  I'm not sure there is any alternative.  Which shell (or set of shells) are you using — it matters?  POSIX doesn't define shell arrays, indexed or associative, so any such notation is an extension over the plain POSIX shell (as implemented by `dash`, for example).

Comment: I am using `GNU bash, version 4.3.11`. I actually have a list of strings that I need to convert into arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by returning the string form of the associative array and then assigning that string to a new associative array in the calling context.

```bash
process_ls_entry() {
    IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$1"
    declare -A LS_MAP
    LS_MAP[entry]="${array[@]::1}"
    LS_MAP[mode]="${array[@]:1:1}"
    LS_MAP[size]="${array[@]:2:1}"
    LS_MAP[num_blocks]="${array[@]:3:1}"
    timestamp="${array[@]:4}"
    timestamp=${timestamp// /_}
    LS_MAP[timestamp]="${timestamp}"
    echo "${LS_MAP[@]@K}" # Expand associative array as string.
}

a="temp_dir drwxr-xr-x 0 0 Fri Jul 13 07:08:00 2012"
# Call function and assign output string to new associative array.
declare -A output="($(process_ls_entry "$a"))"
for key in "${!output[@]}"; do
    echo "output[${key}]=${output[${key}]}"
done
```

Output:

```
output[mode]=drwxr-xr-x
output[entry]=temp_dir
output[num_blocks]=0
output[timestamp]=Fri_Jul_13_07:08:00_2012
output[size]=0
```

In Bash an associative array can be assigned with a string that simply contains a list of alternating keys and values.

> When assigning to an associative array, the words in a compound
> assignment may be either assignment statements, for which the subscript
> is required, or a list of words that is interpreted as a sequence of
> alternating keys and values: NAME=(KEY1 VALUE1 KEY2 VALUE2 ... ).
> https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

An associative array can be expanded into that form with the `@K` parameter expansion operator.

> ${parameter@operator}
>
> The expansion is either a transformation of the value of parameter or information about parameter itself, depending on the value of operator. Each operator is a single letter:
>
> K: Produces a possibly-quoted version of the value of parameter, except
> that it prints the values of indexed and associative arrays as a
> sequence of quoted key-value pairs (see Arrays).
> https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

There doesn't seem to be any difference between indexing with `[*]` or `[@]` before the `@K` operator.  Both `"${assoc[*]@K}"` and `"${assoc[@]@K}"` evaluate to the same single string.

There is also `@Q`, but that only expands to the values and doesn't include the keys.

> Q: The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

Another demo for associative arrays:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function return_assoc() {
    declare -A assoc # Declaration required for associative arrays.
    assoc[zero]=0
    assoc[one]=1
    assoc[two]=2
    echo "${assoc[@]@K}" # Expand in key-value form.
}

# This printf statement will print each argument on it's own line.
printf "%s\n" "$(return_assoc)" # Only a single string is returned.

# Receive an associative array from a function:
declare -A assoc="($(return_assoc))"

echo "${assoc}" # Expansion should be empty, since it's an associative array.
echo "${assoc[@]@Q}" # Print all values.
echo "${assoc[@]@K}" # Print all key-value pairs.

# Loop through all keys in the array and print their values.
for a in "${!assoc[@]}"; do
    echo "assoc[${a}]=${assoc[${a}]}"
done
```

Output:

```
two "2" one "1" zero "0" 

'2' '1' '0'
two "2" one "1" zero "0" 
assoc[two]=2
assoc[one]=1
assoc[zero]=0
```

And for completeness, the same demo with an indexed array:

```
function return_array() {
    declare -a array # Declaration optional for indexed arrays.
    array[0]=zero
    array[1]=one
    array[2]=two
    echo "${array[@]@Q}" # Expand in quoted form.
}

# This printf statement will print each argument on it's own line.
printf "%s\n" "$(return_array)" # Only a single string is returned.

# Receive an indexed array from a function:
declare -a array="($(return_array))"

echo "${array}" # Expands to the first element (array[0]).
echo "${array[@]@Q}" # Print all values.
echo "${array[@]@K}" # Print all index-value pairs.

# Loop through all values in the array.
for a in "${!array[@]}"; do
    echo "array[${a}]=${array[${a}]}"
done
```

Output:

```
'zero' 'one' 'two'
zero
'zero' 'one' 'two'
0 "zero" 1 "one" 2 "two"
array[0]=zero
array[1]=one
array[2]=two
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dreaded `eval` (if you can trust output from `process_ls_entry()`) you can do this:

```
process_ls_entry() {
    IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$1"
    declare -A LS_MAP
    LS_MAP[entry]="${array[@]::1}"
    LS_MAP[mode]="${array[@]:1:1}"
    LS_MAP[size]="${array[@]:2:1}"
    LS_MAP[num_blocks]="${array[@]:3:1}"
    timestamp="${array[@]:4}"
    timestamp=${timestamp// /_}
    LS_MAP[timestamp]="${timestamp}"
    # dump LS_MAP in shell reusable format
    declare -p LS_MAP
}
```

Then call it as:

```
a="temp_dir drwxr-xr-x 0 0 Fri Jul 13 07:08:00 2012"
tmp=$(process_ls_entry "$a")

# use eval to declare same array with a different name output
eval "${tmp/LS_MAP=/output=}"

echo "${output[timestamp]}"
```

**Output:**

```
Fri_Jul_13_07:08:00_2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that seems to do the trick.

```
process_ls_entry() {
    read -r -a array <<< "$1"

    local timestamp="${array[4]}"
    timestamp=${timestamp// /_}

    # Print the right hand side of an associative array expression.
    # This will allow the caller to assign it to a variable name
    # of their choosing.
    printf '(
      [entry]=%q
      [mode]=%q
      [size]=%q
      [num_blocks]=%q
      [timestamp]=%q
    )' "${array[@]::4}" "$timestamp"
}

print_ls_map() {
    local -n ls_map=$1
    echo "The keys of LS_MAP are ${!ls_map[@]}"
    echo "The values of LS_MAP are ${ls_map[@]}"
}

a="temp_dir drwxr-xr-x 0 0 Fri Jul 13 07:08:00 2012"

# -r = readonly
declare -rA LS_MAP=$(process_ls_entry "$a")

# And you can even 'pass' the array to a function using
# named references
# output:
#     The keys of LS_MAP are mode size timestamp num_blocks entry
#     The values of LS_MAP are drwxr-xr-x 0 Fri_Jul_13_07:08:00_2012 0 temp_dir
print_ls_map LS_MAP
```

Comment: This will blow up if the array entries contain any special characters or whitespace. I'd advise encoding them with `printf '%q'`.

Comment: (I've edited my suggestion in. Apologies if I made a typo; I'm not at a computer where I can test my change. Please fix or revert my edit if you don't agree with it.)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into printf.  In the meantime, do you mind expanding on your first comment, perhaps with a short example of something that could go wrong with using echo "([key]=$value)"?